# Move CSS ::after element into element

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone I was wondering how I get the `::after` element from my `<input>` search field into the input field itself (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc1MU.png).

I've tried some things but at the end my result was to set the CSS style for the `::after` element to `margin-left: -25px;`.

I am not sure if this is the best solution, especially because I am using a negative value for margin. Is there any better solution for this? Or is this the only way?

Comment: Use `position` for it.

Comment: [I can't get `::after` to work with an `<input>` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field). Perhaps you should include a [mcve] showing what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it using `position`:

```
.parentElement {
    position: relative;
}

.childElement {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: -25px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is a better solution and was exactly what I was searching for.